# Emacs mode specific keybinding - Symbol's value as variable is void error

Tags: emacs, keyboard-shortcuts

I have tried to set rst-mode specific keybinding such as:

```
(eval-after-load "rst-mode"
      (define-key rst-mode-map (kbd "<f5>") 
                (lambda ()
                  (interactive)
                  (shell-command "make html"))))
```

But I get:

```
Symbol's value as variable is void: rst-mode-map
```

Edited: thanks to the help, I've got the following working version:

```
(eval-after-load "rst"
  '(progn 
     (define-key rst-mode-map (kbd "<f5>") 
       (lambda ()
         (interactive)
           (shell-command (concat "make " "html"))))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`eval-after-load` requires the form to be quoted:

```
(eval-after-load "rst-mode"
  '(define-key ...))
```

(otherwise you are evaluating the form *immediately* instead of after rst-mode has loaded.)

Comment: Thanks a lot. After adding ' in front of (define-key ..., I am not getting the error, but now the keybinding is not applied when I load a .rst file in emacs.

Comment: In this case you need `eval-after-load "rst"` (or `'rst`) not `"rst-mode"`. See `C-h f eval-after-load` for details.

Comment: you can use (symbol-function 'rst-mode) to get autoload name for eval-after-load.